# To say something indirecty to someone through telling it to a third person

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

Please imagine the person "A" is not going to tell something directly to the person "B" in a company. "A" says it to "C" who has a more friendly relations with "A", but in the manner that "C"  (who is a witness to the conversation between "A" and  "C") could hear it. In this way, "A" has succeeds to convey his message to "B" **indirectly**.

**Example:**

Let's imagine that cigaratte smoke bothers "A". "B" who is a chain-smoker is familiar with "A", but still they are not so close together so that "A" could ask him not to smoke beside "A". Now, these three people are together and "A" is talking to "B" who is "A's" intimate friend. "A" tells to "C":

> **A)** I have a college at work who smokes too much! We talked to each other yesterday about his personal issue; he smoked so much that I even couldn't breath! Last night, when I went home, my wife approached me and got surprised. She asked me whether I smoked! You know! It was really difficult to explain it to her! 
>   **C)** Really?! But if I were you, I'd ask him to be more considerate! 
>   **B)** Hears this conversation and tells to himself...................

There is a saying in my language which can describe the action that "A" did in my scenario:

> - He beats one to frighten another.

To me it strikes as a translated version of a proverb from another language; I would appreciate it if you could help me to find a natural way to imply the same meaning in English?

**Added**

Another scenario:

> - Please imagine a bully picks on someone once and the person somehow gets it through the guy that he's not itching for a fight (he doesn't afraid of the guy at all.) Later, the person somewhere meets an intimate friend and suddenly faces the bully who's his friend's close friend! He values this time and just after greetings relates the story of his last championship in the world UFC fights to his own friend in the manner that the bully could heard it too. In this way, without any fight, the person succeeds get this message through the bully that he never ever afraids of him; just he did not tend to fight with him.

In our language, we use only one saying to describe the situation for both cases! We say:

> - He says to the door so that the wall could hear it.

Where "A" is simply talking to "C" so that "B" heard it (with no offence to "C"; (perhaps because "C" is "A's close friend and won't take any offence" or "C" is somehow well-aware about the matter and cooperating with "A").

Comment: Anglophones have borrowed a usage from French: [*pour encourager les autres.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pour%20encourager%20les%20autres) This matches your translation *(beat one to frighten another)* - but it doesn't seem to match your example, where A is simply *talking* to C (apparently with the deliberate intention of being overheard by the actual offender B), not actually *punishing* C. Are you *sure* your example illustrates the required context?

Comment: I have added some extra explanations to my thread @FumbleFingers. Please let me know if there is any other ambiguity yet. Meanwhile, I think your offered saying fits well my second scenario; what do you think?

Comment: You can say A **let/allowed himself be overheard** talking to B, or **ensured he could be overheard** or anything similar.